# How to hide/show activity in moodle based on results of scorm completion

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I'm attempting to bring back a user's scorm 'lesson status' i.e. 'incomplete', 'complete' etc. With this value I will then hide or show the certificate activity based on whether the SCORM file has been marked as complete or not.

```
function block_iomad_progress_monitorable_modules() {
    global $DB;
    $completedCheck = "SELECT id
                                     FROM {scorm_scoes_track}
                                    WHERE scormid = :eventid
                                      AND userid = :userid
                                      AND element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status'
                                      AND {$DB->sql_compare_text('value')} = 'completed'"



    if ($completedCheck == "completed") {
    $link = html_writer::tag('a', $iomadcertificate->name, array('class' => 'dimmed',
            'href' => $CFG->wwwroot . '/mod/iomadcertificate/view.php?id=' . $iomadcertificate->coursemodule));;    
    } else {
        $link = html_writer::tag('a', $iomadcertificate->name, array('class' => 'dimmed',
                'href' => $CFG->wwwroot . '/mod/iomadcertificate/view.php?id=' . $iomadcertificate->coursemodule)); 
    }
```

This is what i've managed to come up with so far, but it is still incorrect and I don't seem to be getting anywhere. I believe it may be my hide/shows. Can anyone point in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is complete code of your function then you're missing few things.

First of all you need to execute your query on database, because what you're doing now in if condition is comparing string with sql query to different string "completed".

Assuming you fix it. I would approach this way:

- Change your query to utilize count. (or use Moodle function
  $DB->count_records_sql [Moodle Docs Reference](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Seeing_how_many_records_match_a_given_criterion)
- Then in if condition check whether it's greater than zero.

You can do this in many ways but without extra logic writing
*$completedCheck == "completed"*  won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle has a basic function to make activities interdependent from each other.

The function is called "restrict access".

Your needed function is restricted access in reference to activity completion. Perhaps, restricted access in reference to grades will also work.

https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Restrict_access_settings

Maybe you do not need your own development?

Greetins